# compare 2 varchar for partial match

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

```
  Table1
+---------------+
| varchar1      |
+---------------+
| aaa, aba, aab |
| aac, aca, caa |
+---------------+ 


  Table2
+---------------+
| varchar2      |
+---------------+
| bbb, abb, aba |
| bbc, bcb, cbb |
+---------------+
```

How to compare the `varchar` from 2 different tables for a partial match?

Such that `aaa, aba, aab` from `Table1` matches with `bbb, abb, aba` from `Table2` because both contains `aba`.

Comment: Don't store comma delimited strings in a database. If this was properly normalised the query would be trivial.

Comment: Can you modify the tables?

Comment: I know how to write the query if the tables are normalised but if I normalised it, I would have to rethink my web form GUI and data entry/retrieval/modification. So I am extremely reluctant to normalise it.

Comment: Normalize it. This is just one of the many problems you'll have going forward. Normalize it now.

Comment: I agree, websites/GUIs are much easier to change than trying to work around a poor database layout later on

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you REALLY should normalize this.  That's definitely a better solution than having to parse out strings like this.  However, if you really wanted to, you could do something like this:

```
Dim varchar1 As IEnumerable(Of String) = {"aaa, aba, aab", "aac, aca, caa"}
Dim varchar2 As IEnumerable(Of String) = {"bbb, abb, aba", "bbc, bcb, cbb"}
Dim varchar1Tokens As IEnumerable(Of String) = (From foo In varchar1
                                                Let tokens = foo.Split(","c)
                                                From bar In tokens
                                                Select bar.TrimEnd)
Dim varchar2Tokens As IEnumerable(Of String) = (From foo In varchar2
                                                Let tokens = foo.Split(","c)
                                                From bar In tokens
                                                Select bar.TrimEnd)
Dim matches As IEnumerable(Of String) = (From item In varchar1Tokens
                                         Where varchar2Tokens.Contains(item)
                                         Select item)

For Each match As String In matches
  Console.WriteLine(match)
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```